# Linking a File Table from Microsoft SQL Server to a table within Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016, filetable

I've used the standard method of linking tables from a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database into an Access 2016 database. Every table linked correctly except for a File Table. Within Access, the linked table displays the File Table's fields but not the records. How can I create a linked table within Access that correctly displays all the contents of the File Table that are within the SQL Server database?

I've tried using updated drivers to create the DSN to allow for connection to the SQL Server. There is an integrated test within the DSN creation wizard that displays the connection is successful.

I expected the linked table within Access to display the contents of the File Table within the SQL Server database, but it displays the following images and an ODBC--call failed error message:

[image: errorMsg]

[image: linked table within Access]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using the concept of views in the SQL database. Linking directly to the File Table was causing issues due to a field conversion problem that corrupted the rest of the linked table in Access.

Instead of directly linking to the File Table in the database, I created and linked to a view that picked certain fields that were needed for the linked table in Access. The view allowed me to not have to link a corrupt field, and as a result, allowed me to link everything that would work in Access.

Comment: IMO it would improve the answer if you'd add your CREATE VIEW statement.